# How to add aria-label attribute to a link in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wai-aria

I'm trying to add the aria-label attribute to a link to make it more accessible. When I'm doing this, it works as expected:

```
<a href="/" class="site-name <%= is_active('home') %>" aria-label="<%= get_aria_label_current_page('home') %>">Version Postman</a>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<%= link_to t('nav.projects'), projects_path, class: is_active('projects'), aria-label: get_aria_label_current_page('home') %>
```

I get an "unexpected tLABEL" syntax error. Anyone knows what's the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's the dash on the label creating the problem. Try this instead:

```
<%= link_to t('nav.projects'),
            projects_path, class: is_active('projects'),
            'aria-label' => get_aria_label_current_page('home') %>
```

**Update**

In ruby 2.2 now you could do:

```
'aria-label': get_aria_label_current_page('home')
```

Answer (score 21):

As of at least Rails 5.2 this works too:

```
<%= link_to t('nav.projects'),
            projects_path,
            class: is_active('projects'),
            aria: { label: get_aria_label_current_page('home') } %>
```

This is similar to how `data-*` attributes work, which is nice since you can add more than one and have them grouped.

This may work on earlier versions but I have not checked.